# Would the CD4053 still be capable of handling tiny voltages?

Tags: cmos, analog-switch

Since the CD4053 and other CMOS ICs can't handle a bi-polar 12V circuit, I was wondering if the CD4053  would still be accurate once the control signals / audio has be scaled down to millivolts operating the CD4053 on a bipolar 5 volt supply.

The control voltages in the circuit can swing anywhere between 180 millivolt down to -400 millivolt after a voltage divider and anything between. Would the CD4053, CD4066 and company still be accurate like a physical track on a PCB?

[image]

Comment: Consider **control-signal** and **audio signal** separately. Control signal (example: pin 11) is *strictly digital*, while the audio (example: pins 12,13,14) can be any analog voltage within DC chip limits. *Do not* try to use the control signal as a smooth-move between channel A and channel B...use it as a switch: either channel A **or** channel B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control signal should swing between 0 and 5V for the 4053 and between -5V and +5V for the 4066 (no internal level shifter for the latter).

For signals, the 'on' channel is much higher resistance than a PCB trace (perhaps some hundreds of ohms, it's well described on the datasheet- nonlinear and varies with temperature) but does not have any offset voltage. The 'off' state has very little leakage and a bit of capacitive coupling.

One subtle thing is that, especially for higher swings in relation to the supply voltage, the variation of transmission gate resistance with voltage can add distortion. You can minimize that by using the lowest resistance analog switch and minimizing the loading. There are much better analog switches than the 4000-series CMOS but they generally are much pricier.

So, generally there's no trouble switching a signal in the mV, but make sure your control voltages are appropriate levels.

Comment: i'm aware that the CD4053 has a internal resistance of about 125 ohm (according to datasheet). the cd4053 can operate fine on a bipolar supply, it has 3 pins, VDD, VSS, GND. ... done that before, awesome ic and the newer ic's. but my supplier doesn't have them.
Just wanted to know if it would still do the job fine if the switched voltage are so minute. within -0.5 Volt and + 0.5 volt.

Comment: Yes, it will switch low voltages. Millivolts, microvolts. Whether that 'does the job' for you depends on your requirements, as outlined above. The 'on' resistance should be less than 550 ohms with a 10V supply voltage, as described in the datasheet. Leakage currents are also characterized. [Figure 2](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf) shows *typical* on resistance changes with voltage and temperature. Maximum is higher, of course.

Comment: Ok, thank you will give it a try.